# Solvability of quasilinear elliptic equations on closed manifolds

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Is there any reference about solvability theory of quasilinear elliptic equations on closed manifolds?

In particular, I am looking for solvability condition for function $f$ of following equation
$\Delta u+ c |\nabla u|^2=f$ on a closed manifold $M$, $c$ is a positive constant. As far as I understand $\int_M\, \Delta u+c |\nabla u|^2\, dV=\int_M\, c |\nabla u|^2\, dV\geq 0$, so at least $\int_M\, f\, dV\geq 0$, is that enough? Is there any sufficient condition for solvability?

Thanks a lot.

---

Now seems like the statement of the problem can be simplified as following

Under what condition for $f$, there exists positive solution $u$ for the Schrodinger equation $\Delta u+f u=0$ on a closed manifold.

Comment: At the maximum value of $u$, $f$ must be negative, so you would also need an $f$ that changes sign -- i.e., the integral condition is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider the case of periodic solutions in one dimension, and let c=1. That is, we have the equation
$$u''+(u')^2=f.$$
Multiply both sides by $e^u$. You end up with
$$(e^u)''=e^uf.$$
Now if, for instance, $f$ is positive, then the right hand side is positive, and the left hand side has zero average, which cannot be.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, then is there any sufficient condition?

Answer (score 0):

Let $w=e^{cu}$, then the equation for $w$ is
$$\Delta w-cfw=0,$$
which is a Schrodinger equation. A necessary for a Schrodinger equation to have a positive solution is Barta's lemma: 
$$\lambda_1(-\Delta+cf)\geq 0.$$

Comment: Is it sufficient?

Comment: Yes, I think it is necessary and sufficient. You can check Barta's Lemma in this paper (Lemma 3.1): http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2705